# jQuery if or while loops

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I haven't done much (or any) jQuery. I found the following script on here to, but I have a question. All the attempts I've tried while searching this site have ruined the script. I only want it sum the values of the other columns if the checkbox is checked.

Here is an example table:

```
<table id="sum_table" class="example">
<thead>
    <tr class="titlerow">
        <td class="table-sortable:numeric">Apple</td>
        <td class="table-sortable:numeric">Orange</td>
        <td class="table-sortable:numeric">Watermelon</td>
        <td class="table-sortable:numeric">Turtle</td>
    </tr>
</thead>

    <tr>
    <td class="rowDataSd">52</td>
    <td class="rowDataSd">911</td>
    <td class="rowDataSd">911</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="rowDataSd">989</td>
    <td class="rowDataSd">24</td>
    <td class="rowDataSd">911</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="rowDataSd">989</td>
    <td class="rowDataSd">911</td>
    <td class="rowDataSd">911</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Here's the script:

```
$('#sum_table tr:first td').each(function(){

     var $td = $(this);  
     var colTotal = 0;

     $('#sum_table tr:not(:first,.totalColumn)').each(function(){
         colTotal  += parseInt($(this).children().eq($td.index()).html(),10);
     });

     $('#sum_table tr.totalColumn').children().eq($td.index()).html('Total: ' + colTotal);
});
```

Where would I put an &&, and what exactly would that && be?

I've tried adding &&s, but I'm just not familiar with how to read jQuery. I'd love to learn it and I thought this would be a simple project. Guess not. As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `&&` is the JavaScript logical AND operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: jQuery doesn't have if or while loops. Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: Whoops sorry. I only said if and while because that's what I assumed it would be called. Regardless, I want the script to only sum those values that contain a checked checkbox.

Comment: Wrap everything that isn't in the thead in the tbody, then you won't have to filter out the first row.

Comment: I've edited my title to be more accurate, then.

Comment: Where is your tr with class `.totalColumn` ?

Comment: Thanks @kevin-b, but I'm actually concerned with filtering out the rows in the tbody

Comment: @PSL, it's in a portion that I didn't post. I added it now.

Comment: the `,` you used in your existing code would be an example of a `||` (such as `.foo,.bar`), and an example of an `&&` would simply be `.foo.bar` which means an element that has both classes `foo` and `bar`

Comment: You want to sum the values in each column, of the values in the rows with a checked checkbox?

Comment: Yes @david-thomas, that's exactly what I want to do. Sum the values of each of columns 1-3 if column 4 has a checked checkbox.

Comment: @kevin-b, so would I do something like this:

$('#sum_table tr:not(:first,.totalColumn) td.is(':checked')')

Comment: @Justin like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/MaNAW/

Comment: @PSL, you're awesome.

That works perfectly!

Comment: @Justin That was it what is the 4th column in total for?

Comment: @PSL, sorry, that "Total:" shouldn't be there. When I started I was merely summing all columns and then decided I wanted to select which to be summed.

Comment: Yes of course @PSL please do

Comment: @Justin Added a much more simpler version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Much more simpler version.

```
 $('[name="cb"]').change(function () { // Add change event for your check boxes
    $('.totalColumn td:lt(3)').html("0"); // reset the sum tds to value 0
    $('[name="cb"]:checked').closest('tr').find('td:lt(3)').each(function () { //Loop through all the tds(but last one) for the rows of checked checkboxes
        var $td = $(this);   
        var $sumColumn = $('#sum_table tr.totalColumn td:eq(' + $td.index() + ')'); //get the correspoding column in the total checkbox relative to the current td iterated
        var currVal = $sumColumn.html() || 0; // Get the value from the column, incase it has no value default it to 0
        currVal = +currVal + +$td.html(); // add the value
        $sumColumn.html(currVal); // populate the column in the total checkbox relative to the current td iterated
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZgnL/)

- **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**
- **[:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)**

Comment: Thanks again @PSL, the notes are helpful also.

Comment: @Justin You are welcome. if you don't understand a jq related stuff you can just look up i will add the link to the answer anyways.. and avoid so many loops.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't validated and just wrote it up quick in notepad++.  The gist of it is that you want to loop through each of your table cell's that have the "rowDataSd" class.  By going to it's parent(), you can easily access that checkbox to see if it is checked.  If it is checked then you just grab the value, make sure to parse it into an int and add it to your total.

```
var total = 0;
$('table#sum_table > tr > td.rowDataSd').each(function() {
    var checked = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0;
    if (!checked) continue; //Keep looping, the checkbox isn't checked

    // Add value to total for current <td />
    total += parseInt($(this).html());
});
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks so much @mattijo, I gave it a try and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on your code : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/129/

The sum is calculated by rows, hope that is what you expected.

However, this is how to perform the sum of a columns :

```
//Iterate all td's in second column
$('#sum_table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').each( function(){
    var tmp = parseInt($(this).text());
    if ($.isNumeric(tmp)) 
        total += tmp;    
});
```

JS :

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    //Return if unchecked
    if($(this).is(':checked') === false)
    {
        $('#total').val("select a row");
        return false;
    }

    //Unselect all other checkbox
    $("input:checkbox").not($(this)).prop('checked',false);

    //Sum of the row
    var total = 0;
    $('td', $(this).closest('tr')).each(function () {
        var tmp = parseInt($(this).text());
        if ($.isNumeric(tmp)) 
            total += tmp;
    }).promise().done(function () {
        //Update the final value destination
        $('#total').val(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

This is rather convolted but here goes:

```
$('#sum_table').change(function () {
    var that = $(this);

    if (that.find("input:checked")) {

        that.find("input:checked").each(function () {
            var checkedTdValue= 0;
            $(this).parent().parent().children('.rowDataSd').each(function () {
                 checkedTdValue += parseInt($(this).text());

            });
            //Put your target here
            $('div').text(checkedTdValue);
        })
    }
});
```